# Is it possible to remotely download youtube videos with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remotely download videos with javascript but I am having some problems.
Here is the HTML:

```html
<button onclick = "downloadRemote();">
Download youtube video
</button>
```

And here is the javascript:

```js
function downloadRemote(){
var URL = this.window.URL || this.window.webkitURL;
var file = new Blob(
    ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWDbSopp8SQ"],
    {"type" : "video\/mp4"});
    const link = document.createElement("a");
var name = 'file.mp4';


  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  link.download = name;
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)

}
```

But for some reason it does not work. It downloads the video, but when I click on it in my files, it just shows up blank. Can someone please help me to make this work as intended. Thank your for all your help in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly how you're intending to use the `Blob()` constructor to download a video from YouTube...? Have you read what [`Blob` actually does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)? Can you share how you know that "*It downloads the video*"?

Comment: Since the URLs YouTube provides execute AJAX, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main problems here:

1. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWDbSopp8SQ` is a URL to an HTML document, not a video
2. The array you pass to `new Blob` needs to contain the *data* you want to put into it, not a URL. You are effectively creating a text file with a URL in it.

So to achieve what you want you would need to:

1. Work out the actual URL to the video (and YouTube very likely doesn't have a plain HTTP URL to a video in the first place)
2. Download it (which would require permission from YouTube via CORS… which they won't provide)
3. Put *that* data in the Blob.

Comment: But what about this guy:

https://blog.usejournal.com/how-i-made-my-own-youtube-downloader-using-javascript-and-node-js-160b172f6e10

Comment: That guy works out the actual URL (as I said you needed to) and doesn't use client-side JS (so doesn't need permission via CORS)

Comment: They are using serverside JavaScript, which means the issue #2 does not exist - CORS is not applicable to serverside scripts. They are also using a library that does the URL-finding and downloading, solving the issue #1.

Comment: OK I found the url it is : https://youtu.be/we7rtglM9fc
Now what do I do?

Comment: @LandonSooHoo — That URL also points to an HTML document.

Comment: OK, well if you could give an example of what you are trying to tell me that would be great :).

Comment: He is trying to tell you that it is not possible to do it clientside. Even if you managed to figure out the URL, the CORS restriction cannot be circumvented without the use of a server. (And if you do have a server, the article gives a very good step-by-step tutorial of how to do it.)

Comment: That would require that I invest a significant amount of time to learn how YouTube serves up actual videos. So no. Go and reverse engineer the library used in by "that guy" instead.

Comment: OK. How would I do this with a local video?